# How I can use Vars on PyQt5 the same way as IntVar() or StringVar() on tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

create the variables

```
region = {'top': tk.IntVar(), 'left': tk.IntVar(), 'right': tk.IntVar(), 'bottom': tk.IntVar()}
```

create the entrys and connect to the variabless

```
tk.Entry(master, textvariable=region['top']).place(x=60, y=100)
tk.Entry(master, textvariable=region['left']).place(x=60, y=120)
tk.Entry(master, textvariable=region['right']).place(x=60, y=140)
tk.Entry(master, textvariable=region['bottom']).place(x=60, y=160)
```

I use the variables on some functions

```
def get_region():
    np.array(ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(region['top'].get(), region['left'].get(), region['right'].get(), region['bottom'].get())))
```

And use the variables to save and open profiles on the app

```
def open_file(self):
    with open('{}'.format(filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/", title="Select file",
                                                     filetypes=(("json files", "*.json"),
                                                                ("all files", "*.*")))), 'r') as config:
        data = json.load(config)

        region['top'].set(data['region']['top'])
        region['left'].set(data['region']['left'])
        region['right'].set(data['region']['right'])
        region['bottom'].set(data['region']['bottom'])

def save_as(self):
    json.decoder = {
        'region': {
            'top': region['top'].get(),
            'left': region['left'].get(),
            'right': region['right'].get(),
            'bottom': region['bottom'].get(),
            },
        }

    with open('{}'.format(filedialog.asksaveasfilename(initialdir="/", title="Save file",
                                                       filetypes=(("json files", "*.json"),
                                                                  ("all files", "*.*")))), 'w',
              encoding='utf-8') as config:
        json.dump(json.decoder, config, ensure_ascii=False, indent=2)
        config.close()
```

What I use in PyQt5 instead of the IntVar() to structure like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no similar element in Qt (there are 2 different libraries whose approach is different), a possible solution is to create an object that maps the qproperties:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
import json
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sip


@dataclass
class Property:
    qobject: QtCore.QObject = None
    qproperty: str = ""

    @property
    def value(self):
        if self.qobject and not sip.isdeleted(self.qobject):
            return self.qobject.property(self.qproperty)

    @value.setter
    def value(self, value):
        if self.qobject and not sip.isdeleted(self.qobject):
            self.qobject.setProperty(self.qproperty, value)


class Widget(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        top_spinbox = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(maximum=2147483647)
        left_spinbox = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(maximum=2147483647)
        right_spinbox = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(maximum=2147483647)
        bottom_spinbox = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(maximum=2147483647)

        button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tr("grab"), clicked=self.grab_screen)

        file_menu = self.menuBar().addMenu(self.tr("&File"))

        open_action = file_menu.addAction(self.tr("Open File..."))
        open_action.triggered.connect(self.load_config)

        save_action = file_menu.addAction(self.tr("Save"))
        save_action.triggered.connect(self.save_config)

        central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)
        flay = QtWidgets.QFormLayout(central_widget)
        flay.addRow(button)
        flay.addRow("Top:", top_spinbox)
        flay.addRow("Left:", left_spinbox)
        flay.addRow("Right:", right_spinbox)
        flay.addRow("Bottom:", bottom_spinbox)

        self.resize(640, 480)

        self.region = {
            "top": Property(qobject=top_spinbox, qproperty="value"),
            "left": Property(qobject=left_spinbox, qproperty="value"),
            "right": Property(qobject=right_spinbox, qproperty="value"),
            "bottom": Property(qobject=bottom_spinbox, qproperty="value"),
        }

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def grab_screen(self):
        top = self.region["top"].value
        left = self.region["left"].value
        right = self.region["right"].value
        bottom = self.region["bottom"].value

        print(top, left, right, bottom)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def load_config(self):
        filename, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
            self,
            self.tr("Select file"),
            "/",
            self.tr("JSON files (*.json);;All files (*.*)"),
        )
        if filename:
            with open(filename, "r") as f:
                data = json.load(f)
                if "region" in data:
                    self.region["top"].value = data["region"].get("top", 0)
                    self.region["left"].value = data["region"].get("left", 0)
                    self.region["right"].value = data["region"].get("right", 0)
                    self.region["bottom"].value = data["region"].get("bottom", 0)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def save_config(self):
        filename, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(
            self,
            self.tr("Save file"),
            "/",
            self.tr("JSON files (*.json);;All files (*.*)"),
        )
        if filename:
            with open(filename, "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
                data = {
                    "region": {
                        "top": self.region["top"].value,
                        "left": self.region["left"].value,
                        "right": self.region["right"].value,
                        "bottom": self.region["bottom"].value,
                    },
                }

                json.dump(data, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=2)


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

QLineEdit example:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sip


@dataclass
class Property:
    qobject: QtCore.QObject = None
    qproperty: str = ""

    @property
    def value(self):
        if self.qobject and not sip.isdeleted(self.qobject):
            return self.qobject.property(self.qproperty)

    @value.setter
    def value(self, value):
        if self.qobject and not sip.isdeleted(self.qobject):
            self.qobject.setProperty(self.qproperty, value)


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()

    prop = Property(w, "text")

    # variable for test
    counter = 0

    def on_timeout():
        nonlocal counter
        print("text:", prop.value)
        counter += 1
        prop.value = counter

    timer = QtCore.QTimer(interval=1000, timeout=on_timeout)
    timer.start()

    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks @eyllanesc, I use your example and I was able to make it work some parts of the app, to make it work I abdicate some classes I made and place all on the main class, the others parts not working is because I need to use StringVar(), DoubleVar() and BooleanVar(). Instead of using QSpinbox I need to use QLineEdit and grab text from there I think. When I use the Vars on tkinter I place them all on main class and then I grab them with a controller in the others classes. Can you help me wit that? Thanks

Comment: @Nuno It seems that you have not understood my solution: 1) In Qt the XVar do not exist or will exist, so you have to adapt some things but it will never be perfect, 2) I will add examples of how to use my solution for some types of widget such as the QLineEdit (it won't cover all the Qt widgets but it will give you an idea of how to use it)

Comment: I never used the dataclass before, I think I understand a bit more the class Property, on the first example I change the QSpinbox to QLineEdit and the qproperty to 'text' and converted to int to use in some functions, thanks.